# Flutter firestore structure for query condition

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to NoSQL and I'm trying to figure out a good way to represent my data. I have a series of workers that need to request vacations via mobile app.

[image]

When I try to write a Firebase query with Flutter, I can do this:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("ferie_permessi")
    .document("worker1@test.com")
    .snapshot();
```

It works but there are two main errors:

1. If I try to create another collection called "Woker info" I cannot use `worker1@test.com` as document ID as it already esists;
2. I have to sort data client side because firestore doesn't give me the possibility (with this setup I've made).

I'm quite sure that this structure isn't good at all. Each worker needs to have 2 lists: `vacations` and `other`. What is wrong?

My guess is that I should move `worker1@test.com` together with `vacations` and `other` so that I can make a query of this kind:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("ferie_permessi")
    .where("user", "==", "worker1@test.com)
    .snapshot();
```

But now the id? Is an automatic one good?

Answer (score 1):

I had a chance to recently explore creating an app using a firebase-firestore. A couple of things will help here:

1. Yes, the autogenerated `id` is good since it is unique, for example, you can have a collections `vacation_requests`, `users` you can then use that `user_id` as a document in `vaccation_requests` -> `user_id` -> `vacations`, instead of using email as a document key.

Or

You can do it like this collections `users`, `vacation_requests`, and `requests`.

1. store user details in `users`.
2. store requests in `requests` with `from` and `to` dates.
3. store reference of User and Request in `vaccation_requests`.

Hope this helps!